# PHP regex to strip all characters except letters, numbers, commas, hyphens and underscores

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use a string in a regex to strip out all characters except letters, numbers, commas, hyphens and underscores.

This is the regex I am using at the moment:

`$clean_input = preg_replace("/[^,-\w]+/", "", $input);`

It returns this Warning in my PHP log

`PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 5 in [file]...`

Previously I had used the exact same regex without the comma character which did work (apart from it still stripping commas obviously). It looked like this:

`$clean_input = preg_replace("/[^-\w]+/", "", $input);`

If you check out [this example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bWP) I made in an online regex tester tool it shows the exact same set up I have in my code. It returns the result as I would expect it, stripping everything but the commas.

What is it that might cause an issue from this one comma character. I tried escaping it, but that gave the same warning. Thanks for any help Regex-gods!

Comment: if you want to strip all except letters , numbers or commas then why you put `-` inside the char class?

Comment: What about underscores?

Comment: Sorry, I see where the confusion came. I've updated the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `-` at the start or at the end because hyphen inside a char class has [special meaning](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). and also don't forget to put comma inside the negated character class .

```
$clean_input = preg_replace("/[^-\w,]/", "", $input);
```

Comment: Little extra note: *[...] and underscores.* :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think you just have to explain to OP, that `-` has a special meaning in [character classes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)